# Where/How can I store an iOS device token in the backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I have a Post/Comment style application.

**Models (backend Rails JSON API)**

- I have a User Model (stores id, user name, email, etc)
- I have a RememberToken Model (stores user's digested tokens to remember their 'sessions')

**Desired Outcome**

- User Alice signs up for my application with her iPhone. During sign up, her device_token is also sent, and stored in the backend.
- User Alice creates a new Post, and is stored with post_id 186.
- User Bob reads Alice's Post, and comments. A POST is sent to the /comments URL, and during the saving of the comment... it also checks the owner of the post (post_id 186). It sees the Post Owner is User Alice, looks up her device_token, and send a Push Notification to User Alice's device_token through APNS (Apple Push Notification Sever).
- User Alice's iPhone receives a Push Notification that User Bob has replied to her Post.

**Issue**

Where should the device token be stored?

- **1)** If it were stored on the User model, then the device token could be overwritten when Alice signs into another device. For example, Alice signs in to the app on her iPhone, and her device_token ABC is stored on the users table. Then Alice signs in on her iPod Touch, and its device_token (XYZ) is stored in the users table for her, overwriting ABC. Now she will only receive Push Notifications to her iPod Touch.
- **2)** If it were stored on the RememberToken model, tied to the session, there would be issues with out-of-date remember_tokens. For example. User Bob downloads the app on his iPod Touch (with device_token 123) and signs up. Bob get's a new iPhone (with device token 456), downloads the app on it, and signs in. There are now 2 RememberToken entries which each token/sessions information, and a device_token tied to each one. [Logging out will delete the Remember Token row which is perfect]. However, Bob realizes he doesn't need his iPod Touch anymore, deletes the application without logging out (meaning the RememberToken and DeviceToken of 123 still exists in the DB), and gives it to his little sister Carol. Carol downloads the application, and signs up (creating a RememberToken and DeviceToken of 123). So we now have two DeviceToken entries of 123. User Bob makes a post, User Dave comments, and the backend looks up all of User Bob's device tokens. It finds 123 and 456. It sends Push Notifications to both. So Bob correctly receives a notification on his iPhone, but Carol incorrectly receives a notification on her iPod that doesn't apply to her.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change your account creation flow a little.  You should require uniqueness on device token and when someone registers with an existing device token it should remove any other existing remember tokens with the same device id.  This would apply to registration but not logging in.